# Help interpreting logcat messages related to BackupManager Restore

Tags: backup, restore, backup-manager

Appreciate any help interpreting the following **logcat** messages from an **`adb shell bu restore`** command.

```
06-11 19:41:35.342  1450  3609 I BackupManagerService: Beginning restore...
06-11 19:41:35.342  1450  3609 D BackupManagerService: isPrivilegeBackupApp() pkg name is android.uid.shell:2000 value : false
06-11 19:41:35.342  1450  3609 D BackupManagerService: Starting restore confirmation UI, token=144556548
06-11 19:41:35.386  1450  3609 D BackupManagerService: Waiting for restore completion...
06-11 19:41:38.596  1450  4769 D BackupManagerService: acknowledgeAdbBackupOrRestore : token=144556548 allow=true
06-11 19:41:38.648  1450 15003 I BackupManagerService: --- Performing full-dataset restore ---
06-11 19:51:20.395  1450  1450 V BackupManagerService: Scheduling immediate backup pass
06-11 19:51:20.405  1450  1450 W BackupManagerService: Backup pass but enabled=false setupComplete=true
06-11 19:51:35.390  1450  3412 I BackupManagerService: sep backup/restore timed out waiting for success
06-11 19:51:35.392  1450  3609 I BackupManagerService: adb restore processing complete.
06-11 19:51:35.395  1450 15003 E BackupManagerService: Unable to read restore input
06-11 19:51:35.404  1450 15003 D BackupManagerService: Full restore pass complete.
06-11 19:53:50.976  1450  3412 V BackupManagerConstants: getKeyValueBackupIntervalMilliseconds(...) returns 14400000
06-11 19:53:50.976  1450  3412 V BackupManagerConstants: getKeyValueBackupFuzzMilliseconds(...) returns 600000
06-11 19:53:50.976  1450  3412 V BackupManagerConstants: getKeyValueBackupRequiredNetworkType(...) returns 1
06-11 19:53:50.976  1450  3412 V BackupManagerConstants: getKeyValueBackupRequireCharging(...) returns true
```

---

Specifically does the following indicate a permission problem writing to `/root/data/data` ?

```
> isPrivilegeBackupApp() pkg name is android.uid.shell:2000 value : false 
> Backup pass but enabled=false setupComplete=true
```

Comment: enabled=false probably refers to BackupManager is not enabled

Comment: I would assume that `isPrivilegeBackupApp` is just called to decide if the users has to confirm the process in a UI dialog (isPrivilegeBackupApp=false) or if the restore process can be performed invisible in background without user interaction (isPrivilegeBackupApp=true).

Comment: @alecxs successful backup was performed from the same device, which assume is also managed by BackupManager. Further, wouldn't the other actions shown in  the log indicate BackupManager trying to do work? In any case, how do you separately enable BackupManager?

Comment: The code [from here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/fullsdk/sources/android-28/+/refs/heads/androidx-transition-release/com/android/server/backup/restore/PerformAdbRestoreTask.java) 
 suggests some kind of IOException.  Any help interpreting will be appreciated.